# flutter : how to rebuild all the qpp after change the current language

Tags: flutter, dart

rebuild the app after do something like change the theme or change the current language , iam using the (  easy_localization: ^3.0.0 ) package to change the lang
EasyLocalization(
child: MyApp(currentMode: currentMode),
supportedLocales: const [
Locale('ar'),
Locale('en'),
],
path: 'assets/translations',
startLocale: const Locale('ar'),
assetLoader: const CodegenLoader(),
),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If you're looking for the solution to this problem, this one works perfectly(tested) !

1. Add the package phoenix from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix)
2. Wrap your main widget with Phoenix

```html
void main() {
  runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}
```

3. Call rebirth method anywhere in your app like so `Phoenix.rebirth(context);`

Answer (score 0):

Or make use of state management solutions like riverpod.

You place your settings in a provider and watch it on the pages that should change when the state updates.

Comment: i want to restart all app not some widgets